# How to remove annoying iCloud nagging in Catalina?

Tags: icloud

How do I remove this very annoying thing under System preferences without signing in to iCloud? I do want to be signed in to the app store.

[image]

I do not want to use iCloud.

Answer (score 4):

There are solutions posted here that I'm still a bit unsure about: 
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/i-dont-want-to-use-icloud-but-system-preferences-nags-me-to-start-using-it.2187969/

`defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs` will remove the "1" notif, but there's still annoying imperatives left:

[image]

The red "1" was my biggest problem though, I'm not going to spend more effort right now - there are suggestions that involve booting into recovery and stuff like that which I just can't do right now. All ears for anything better!

Comment: That worked for me but only after also running `killall Dock` to exit and reopen Dock.

Comment: Even though it worked for me in January, now it's not working for me. `Domain (com.apple.systempreferences) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.`

Comment: I think I was able to delete it just now by first running `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0 && killall Dock` and then `defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs && killall Dock`

Answer (score 2):

Added answer here as the linked question below refers back to this one. OSX Monterey

Following a comment suggestion from a different [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392645/459517), I just clicked the "Start Using iCloud" button, and then when it asked me some question about proceeding in exchange for my soul, I clicked "Not Now". For reference, I'm signed into the App Store for apps, updates and such, just not iCloud.

The badge is gone now (even after reboot) and it only appears when I have an update.