# How to remove iCloud alert badge from macOS settings icon

Tags: icloud, catalina, apple-id

How can I get rid of this annoying red badge on the Settings icon? I want to see such a badge when there is an update available, not for making me use iCloud if I don't want or need it.

[image: Start using iCloud]

[image: Apple ID icon]

Comment: Did you try by clicking on "Start Using iCloud" and not actually logging in?

Comment: The question where you found the answer is already linked on top, no need to add a second link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to sign out from iCloud an the App Store and rebooting your Mac?
This solved the problem for many people I know...

I hope this helps!!

Comment: See the edit. I never signed into icloud, only to the appstore.